# Can i use one .htaccess file for different folders on Linux server

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have different folders which i want to prevent access .
But i don't want to separate for different folders.

For i have htaccess and htpasswd applies to

```
/admin1
/admin2
/admin3
```

I want that if user enter username password fro admin1 folder then he will be able to access admin2 and admin3 without entering isername and password again

But if someone only access admin2 then he has type enter username and password

SOmething like single sign on

I am accessing those via web interface http://abc.com/admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are two options.

Option 1)
Have similar, or the same .htaccess files in every directory you wish to protect, which reference a single .htpassword file:

```
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
AuthName "Some Secret FIles"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Option 2)
Symlink a single .htaccess file into every directory (This means if you change anything in your master .htaccess file all the symlinks will be updated

Answer (score 3):

Instead of putting the same file in all the different folders, you could restrict access to a common parent folder instead. E. g. like this:

```
/parent            <-- this folder is protected by .htaccess
/parent/admin1
/parent/admin2
/parent/admin3
```

This way you would only have to maintain a single `.htaccess` file.

A different would be linking the same `.htaccess` file into all three folders using symlinks (if you are on a *nix based OS / on Windows you might use junctions when on NTFS). But I am not sure if Apache allows symlinks as `.htaccess` files

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer is Yes you can use same .htaccess file.

This is how HTTP Authentication works. You can just copy same .htaccess to all three folders and the user will be able to browse all three folders with out being asked for password again. The authentication basically depend on the password file, as far as the password file is same the rest doesn't matter. It will work everywhere on your domain. So you can use the same .htaccess file.

Comment: so u mean , in every folder i copy the same .htaccess and .htpasswd file

Comment: no you can just move the .htpasswd file outside of your document root. and then just change the path to .htpasswd in your .htaccess file. That way you will have single .htpasswd for all 3 directories. And when you will change/update passwords it will be reflected on all 3 directories.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#####
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/admin1 auth=1
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/admin2 auth=1
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/admin3 auth=1

AuthName "Please login"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path_to_file_which_contains_user_login_pwd/.htpasswd

## first, allow everybody
Order Allow,Deny
Satisfy any
Allow from all
Require valid-user
# then, deny only if required
Deny from env=auth
#####
```